# Is there a way I can convert a Oracle linux Slave DNS to a Master DNS server after transfer?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

The purpose of my task is to create a copy of my current dns settings and save it somewhere.
I copied my current DNS zones from a Windows DNS server.   I create a oracle linux slave DNS server.  I transfer all the zones I care about to the linux slave server.  I moved it to a different zone that has no access to the Windows DNS master server and the Linux slave server worked for couple of days but then stop responding.   I figured I needed to somehow convert this slave server to a master server.  I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Please help!!

Comment: BIND distributions usually have manual included. It is also available online https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Converting from `slave` to `master` would only take changing `type slave` to `type master` for each slave `zone` description if you already have zone files specified for each `zone` with `file` statement.

Comment: When I did that the named service will not turn on. It seems like it fails.

Comment: Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-23 18:10:28 CST; 2min 47s ago
  Process: 1530 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: You have syntax errors in your named configuration files.

Comment: Also note that slave zone files (i.e. copied with AXFR/IXFR) will have all comments removed and will probably be in a different order than the original files - in short, it's a dump of the in-memory zone records after the source file has been parsed by the original nameserver, not a copy of the actual file those records came from.  This probably won't matter if the original zones weren't in bind zonefile format.   BTW, if your new nameserver is authoritative only, you might want to consider using [NSD](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/about/) instead of bind.

Comment: @alexd I'm following this instructions https://www.tecmint.com/setup-master-slave-dns-server-in-centos/ but the slave/zone files are all non-human readable.